# Issues in Django migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I ran into a difficult problem related to Django migrations and searching for answer

I created few database models and inserted data on those models by using migrations file

**Example Migrations 0001_users.py**

**Example Model :**

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('user_id', models.CharField(max_length=256)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=256)),
            ],
        )
```

**Example Migrations 0002_users_data.py**

**Example Data:**

```
user = User(user_id="DEV", name="dev")
user.save()

user = User(user_id="STAGE", name="stage")
user.save()
```

Now i add an ForeignKey in above table say **address** with some default value in **Migrations file 0003_updated_column.py** and its working fine locally,as i have already created a table, inserted data and now modifying old data with new column

But, If any new user want to pull as a fresh repo, he is getting issues in running migrations as my first,second migrations file will have hard-coded users table data with out newly added ForeignKey on it but models file will have newly added ForeignKey as well

Please help me on this

Comment: Why isn't your newly added ForeignKey in a migration of its own?

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem for the FK to be in migration 3? That is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Whoops, I misread as the new FK not being in a migration at all.